# Can't find React component in Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I make a modal with bootstrap.

In this modal, I've got a canvas how use react (it's a plugin to make signature with a canvas like Paint).

My problem is that when I'm on Chrome or Mozilla, I don't have any error, but when I'm on Internet Explorer the console, log me an error when I'm used react.

I have already put the meta tag like this :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: What's the error?...

Comment: The console just put Can't find React